# AutoComplete result show in left top of page instead bottom of input in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, spring-mvc, autocomplete

I have autocomplete in jsp:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="${commodityCode_pl}" name="commodityCode" id="commodityCode" maxlength="8" style="width: 120px">
```

And script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#commodityCode").autocomplete({
    minLength:3,
    source:function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />/storeCommodity/storeCommodity/loadByIsCmdCode/" + request.term + ".html", function (list) {
            response(jQuery.map(list.storeCommodities, function (item) {
                return {
                    label:item.commodityCode,
                    value:item.commodityCode
                }
            }))
        });
    },
    select:function (e, ui) {
        $("#commodityCode").html("(" + ui.item.isCmdCode + ")");
      }
    });

  });

</script>
```

But when i run the code, the autocomplete result appear in top-left of jsp page. While it should appear bottom of input field.

Comment: Provide the html to?

Comment: It is too long. Is it necessary to copy it here?

Comment: Use `.after()`, not `.html()` ... `$("#commodityCode").after("(" + ui.item.isCmdCode + ")");`

Comment: My problem is not resolved by use of `.after()`.

Comment: Then you need to post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **appendTo:YourContainerDiv**

1. > ```
   > $("#TextBox").autocomplete({
   >                 appendTo: '.ContainerDiv',
   >                 source: function (request, response) {
   >                     $.ajax({
   >                         url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
   >                         type: "POST",
   >                         dataType: "json",
   >                         data: { Prefix: request.term },
   >                         success: function (data) {
   >                             response($.map(data, function (item) {
   >                                 return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
   >                             }));
   >
   >                         }
   >                     })
   >                 }
   >
   >             });
   > ```